# Python SQL - keep saying 'unsupported format character 'f' (0x66) at index 81' even all attributes' types are correct

Tags: python, sql, database, psycopg2

```
insert_stat = """INSERT INTO measurement 
             VALUES (%(Station)s, %(Date)s, %(Level)f, 
                    %(MeanDischarge)f, %(Discharge)f, %(Temp)f, %(EC)f)"""
```

Here is my insert statement for inserting data into the table.
Here is how my data looks like and the error.

```
OrderedDict(  
[('Station', '219018'),  
('Date', datetime.date(2004, 12, 31)),  
             ('Level', 0.219),  
             ('MeanDischarge', 1.996),  
             ('Discharge', 1.731),  
             ('Temp', None),  
             ('EC', None)]) .
```

db error:

```
unsupported format character 'f' (0x66) at index 81 .
```

I cannot figure out why it keeps showing this error, as all attributes' types are correct.

The question solved. Before I did not know the psycopg converts data type automatically, so I only need to use '%s' instead of use '%f%' even though the data type is float.

Comment: What database and client library are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query string, you always have to use %s placeholders, even when passing a number. All Python objects are converted by Psycopg in their SQL representation, so they get passed to the query as strings.

```
insert_stat = """INSERT INTO measurement 
         VALUES (%(Station)s, %(Date)s, %(Level)s, 
                %(MeanDischarge)s, %(Discharge)s, %(Temp)s, %(EC)s)"""
```

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#faq-float

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem has to do with your use of %s. Try something like the following code instead:

```
insert_stat = “INSERT INTO measurement(Station, Date, Level, MeanDischarge, Discharge) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)”, (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
```

I know this works when directly inserting into a database using sql but I don’t know about creating a string though.